# Sharing an Array between OnClick classes in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, arrays, class, android-intent

I'm writing a code that takes an input from the user, and then the user either clicks the "Enter Another Activity" button or "Done" button.  I'm currently taking the information within the enterAnotherButton onClickListener, but I need to be able to transfer the information to the doneButton onClickListener to send to another Activity via intent.  Here's my current code:

```
public class EnterCourseActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private MainActivity ma;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_enter_course);

    buttonClick();
}

public void buttonClick () {

    Button enterAnotherButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enterAnotherButton);
    enterAnotherButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          int i = 1;
          public void onClick(View view) {
            EditText courseName;
            courseName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputCourseName);
            String courseNameString = courseName.getText().toString();
            String[] courses = new String[i];
            courses[i - 1] = courseNameString;
            i++;
            courseName.setText("");
          }
        });

    Button doneButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.doneButton);
    doneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view){

        }
    });

    //when user clicks doneButton execute this
        ArrayList<String> coursesArrayList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(courses));
        Intent i = new Intent(EnterCourseActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        i.putStringArrayListExtra("course", coursesArrayList);

        startActivity(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @feantury suggested, simply create a class to house the information you are saving. Then you can access the same object upon doneButton click.

```
public void buttonClick () {
    final SampleObj obj = new SampleObj("test");
    Button enterAnotherButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enterAnotherButton);
    enterAnotherButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        int i = 1;
        public void onClick(View view) {
            obj.courseName = "test1";
        }
    });

    Button doneButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.doneButton);
    doneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view){
            Log.d(TAG, "Result of obj: " + obj.courseName);
        }
    });
}

class SampleObj {
    String courseName;

    public SampleObj(String courseName) {
        this.courseName = courseName;
    }
}
```

Clicking enterAnotherButton changes obj.courseName to "test1", which is then accessible in the onClick of doneButton.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing really complex there. Just create a class attribute to store your activity state values. Attributes can be shared between annonymous classes like the ones you are creating for the `onClick` events.

Answer (score 0):

I hope i understood the question properly but this is how i would do it:

```
public class EnterCourseActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private ArrayList<String> courses;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_enter_course);

        courses = new ArrayList<String>();

        buttonClick();
    }

    public void buttonClick () {
        final EditText courseName;
        courseName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputCourseName);

        Button enterAnotherButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enterAnotherButton);
        enterAnotherButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String courseNameString = courseName.getText().toString();
                courses.add(courseNameString);
                courseName.setText("");
            }
        });

        Button doneButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.doneButton);
        doneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view){
                Intent i = new Intent(EnterCourseActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                i.putStringArrayListExtra("courses", courses);

                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
     }
 }
```

So instead of creatring a `String[]` array and then recreating it everytime a new item is added just create the `ArrayList<String>` from the beggining and call `.add(course)` on it everytime the user wants to add a new course.

There is no reason to call `EditText courseName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputCourseName);` inside the `View.OnClickListener()` as you only need to find it once and not everytime a new course is added.

In the done button just start the activity and pass in the `courses` `ArrayList` and now there is also no reason to call `ArrayList<String> coursesArrayList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(courses));`.